# Code First Migrations, Database Projects, and SQL Azure

Tags: ef-code-first, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

We are in the process of developing a new site that we plan to host on Azure. None of us have done this before, so it has raised some interesting challenges.

First, we are using code first and using migrations to update the database. We were having some issues figuring out how to deploy the database to Azure, so we ended up creating a database project.

There are a bunch of Azure specific issues with deployment, and you will get errors if you don't rectify all the valid SQL that Azure doesn't allow you to use.
It seemed to me that you should be able to do code first on the azure site just like we did on the local site, and I found [This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2012/11/13/enable-automatic-code-first-migrations-on-sql-database-in-azure.aspx) that seems to address the issue.

What I am wondering though, is best practices.

1. I would assume we don't need database projects anymore, but I am not
   sure about that. What is the best practice for managing databases
   with Visual Studio 2013 and code first.
2. The approach in the article above seems fine for a system in
   pre-production, but once a system is in production and has live
   data, is this a recommended approach?
   How do you protect yourself from mistakes like somebody accidentally changing a 
   setting that tells Visual Studio to recreate the database?

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First i would like to state from my understanding, when using Entity Framework and you have Enabled Migration, it's only meant for development and it is recommended that you set it to false when deploying your code.

As for deploying to Microsoft Azure, i have only done this using Visual Studio Team Services. The thing about Code-First is that you have no Sql Queries and the database is not deployed right away. So here is what i have done in the past,

1. Create a blank Sql Query in SQL Management Studio
2. In Visual Studio Server Explorer expand your database for the
   project to table level
3. Right click on each table and select "Show Table Definition" I wish
   we could do this at Database level.
4. Copy and past the T-SQL to a blank Sql file in SQL Management
   Studio. Note that all                table queries can fit in one
   file, just have to follow T-SQL rules. Connect to your Azure
   Database Instance using SQL Management Studio.
5. Run the SQL Query against the database on Azure. Note that the
   sample data you had used in developemnt will not be on your Azure
   database at this moment, you will have to create an insert T-SQL and
   run it against the Azure database.

Also make sure that your app has the right connection string when deploying to Microsoft Azure and it should connect to you database just fine.

Comment: While you shouldn't deploy migrations directly to production, it is wrong to say migrations is only for development.  You can still leverage EF Migrations, but generate change scripts using `-Script` option so that you can review changes before running them in production, or hand the script off to a DBA to review.